# Error with eclipse download

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Dell Inpiron Windows Vista Laptop and downloaded the 32 bit eclipse mars. When I unzipped the file and tried to run it I got a message saying "Version 1.6.0_7 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version:1.7 or greater is required" Which version of eclipse is that? Which version will work best for this laptop. I prefer Luna cause that is the one I use at school,but get the same error message so I tried Mars

Comment: Version 1.6.0_7 [Java 6]  of the ***JVM*** is not suitable.  You need to update Java  to at least 1.7 [Java 7].

Comment: The message is telling you that you need Java 7 (or 8) installed to use Eclipse Luna or Mars.

Comment: The issue is not about the version of Eclipse, but the version of JDK. Download and install the latest JDK and that should resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

As it says, Java version:1.7 or greater is required for Eclipse Mars.
You must install at least **java 7** or download **Eclipse Kepler**.

Answer (score 1):

Mars is newer than Luna, and they both require Java 1.7, at least. You can [download it from java.com](https://java.com/en/download/).